# SlidingPaneLayout background color

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingmenu, android-sliding, android-background

I am using [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). Everything works great. :) What I would like to achieve is change the background color of the panel in the image to transparent so that it shows the part of the image behind it. I tried setting background color of the SLidingPaneLayout to transparent but it doesn't work. When I change the color to something else like red, it shows red but doesn't happen the same with transparent.

I also tried setting window background to transparent but it leaves a black background.

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Please help.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.app.custom.SlidingUpPanelLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:blurView="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
sothree:umanoPanelHeight="110dp"
sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="0dp"
sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp">

<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProfileLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/profile" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">


        <com.app.custom.UnscrollableViewPager
            android:id="@+id/facesPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


        <com.app.custom.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>


<!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->

<com.app.custom.FrameLayoutWithBluredBackground
    android:id="@+id/dragView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    blurView:blurRadius="20">


    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/mViewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/layoutImages"
            layout="@layout/layout_faces_thumb" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutMore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/follow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgClickMe"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/graphic" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
</com.app.custom.FrameLayoutWithBluredBackground>
```

Comment: Add your snippet for your SlidingPaneLayout XML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add this line to your SlidingPanel:

```
sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
```

And add transparent to the background in the xml:

```
<com.app.custom.FrameLayoutWithBluredBackground
   android:id="@+id/dragView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:focusable="false"
   blurView:blurRadius="20"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>
```

Comment: It doesn't. :( I have tried setting background to transparent for all the view in my above code but no help

Comment: I had missed the overlay part. Worked. It did. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Can I ask you couple of more questions about SlidingUpPanelLayout?

Comment: You definitely can try (:

Comment: My sliding layout is like 100dp tall, now the height may vary depending upon data. So is there a way, I can show it always on beginning when the page is opened. In short, I do not want to hardcode sothree:umanoPanelHeight="110dp"?

Comment: I don't fully understand, you want to set the height dynamically?

Comment: Yes that will be the last option actually. Can this be sothree:umanoPanelHeight = wrap_content instead of a fix height?

Comment: Of course it wrap content. In addition if you need do this dynamically you can use setPanelHeight()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84387/discussion-between-atul-o-holic-and-yshahak).